# cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk not working in android 31+

Tags: android, cordova

I can't get the **cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk** plugin to work with release builds (it works if I build in debug mode), all my plugins are with the latest version, my cordova and cordova android are also up to date.

I can use the camera and filesystem in the app without any problems, but if I try to use the scanbot the app stays on this screen but doesn't ask the user for permission to use the camera. I also tried to add the camera permission manually in config.xml using:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</edit-config>
```

but it didn't work.

Here is a screenshot of what I see when I try to open the plugin.
[image: screenshot of plugin not working]

Answer (score 1):

Please change your configuration as below

```
<platform name="android">
      <config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
      </config-file>
</platform>
```

also, specify the relative path for `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` with the latest Cordova version.

and follow the below steps after you modify the config.xml

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```